# Scheme: match-lambda syntax error

Tags: syntax, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am writing a function annotate that uses match-lambda often with recursive calls to annotate.  Here is one of the patterns and matches:

```
(`(,<param> . ,<params> (lambda (,<args>) ,<stmt> . ,<stmts>))
 `(CLOSURE ENV ,(append (append `(,<param>) `(,<params>))`(,<args>)) (lambda (ENV) ,(map annotate `(,<stmt> . ,<stmts>)))))
```

I am getting a complaint that the first use of "." is illegal -- between "param" and "params" -- but I can't figure out why.  This pattern and match doesn't get any complaints and seems very similar with regards to the first ".":

```
(`(λ (,<param1> . ,<params>) ,<stmt> . ,<stmts>)
 `(CLOSURE ENV ,(map annotate `(,<param1> . ,<params>)) (λ (ENV) ,(map annotate `(,<stmt> . ,<stmts>)))))
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` needs to be before the last element in the list (except for some Racket-specific syntax that you are not using).  Remember that the general form of a list is `(a b c . d)`, meaning `(cons a (cons b (cons c d)))`.  You might be able to use `,@<params>` to match some elements in the middle of a list, but I am not sure about that.